# Automatically create menu for each post in custom post type using post slug as menu name

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to write a function that for each post in post type "people" creates menu with wp_create_nav_menu() when post is published.

If you have any ideas, I am very eager to see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I fount the solution

```
 `$myPages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'people' AND post_status = 'publish'"); 

foreach ($myPages as $q ){
  $id = 'menu-'.$q->ID;
  $ai_post_title = strtolower($q->post_title);
  $ai_slug_as_menu_title = str_replace(" ", "-", $ai_post_title);
  wp_create_nav_menu( $ai_slug_as_menu_title );
}`
```